# Why is #regex used in task.json in Azure DevOps extension? What does it check for?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-extensions

I came across this and was wondering what this means and how it works?
What's the significance of using #regex here and how does it expand?

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DownloadPackageV0/task.json

```
 "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/{{ **#regex ([a-fA-F0-9\\-]+/)[a-fA-F0-9\\-]+ feed }}_apis**/Packaging/Feeds/{{ **#regex [a-fA-F0-9\\-]*/([a-fA-F0-9\\-]+) feed** }}{{#if view}}@{{{view}}}{{/if}}/Packages?includeUrls=false"
```

Also I would like to know how many packages will it return and display in the Task input UI dropdown if there are thousands of packages in the feed. Is there a known limit like first 100 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#regex` doesn't appear to actually be documented anywhere, but it takes two space-delimited arguments. The first is a regular expression and the second is a "path expression" identifying what value to match against, in this case the value of the `feed` input parameter. If the regex matches the value, it returns the first capturing subexpression, otherwise it returns the empty string.

In this particular context, the `feed` parameter is formatted as 'projectId/feedId', where projectId and feedId are GUIDs, and projectId and the / are eliminated for organization-scoped feeds (i.e. feeds that are not *inside* a project). The first regex therefore extracts the project ID and inserts it into the URL, and the second regex extracts the feed ID and inserts it into the URL.

As of this writing, the default limit on the API it's calling is 1000.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. Is the limit also applicable for the task input U as part of a pickList? Or will the UI populate even less number of pakages due to any other known limits?

Comment: The limit I mentioned is the default limit on the number of entries the API being called there will *return*. I don't know off hand whether there are further limits on the UI side.

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834090/azure-pipeline-custom-task-string-input-to-match-regex

Answer (score -1):

Regex stands for *regular expression*, which allows you to match any *pattern* rather than an exact string. You can find more info on how to use it in Azure Devops [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops)

This regex is very specific. In this case, the regex `([a-fA-F0-9\\-]+/)[a-fA-F0-9\\-]+`\ matches *one or more* of the following 1) letters `a-f` (small or capital) Or 2) `\` Or 3) `-` followed by `/` and then again *one or more* of those characters.

You can copy the regex `[a-fA-F0-9\\-]+/)[a-fA-F0-9\\-]+` into https://regexr.com/ to play around with it, to see what does and doesn't match the pattern. 
Examples:

- **it matches**: `a/a` `a/b` `abcdef-\/dcba`
- but **doesn't match**: `/a`, `abcdef`, `this-doesn't-match`

Note that the full endpoint consists of concatenations of both regular expression and hardcoded strings!

Comment: Thanks for the response Casper! I should have been more specific. I know what Regex is in general but wanted to know how it works in this specific context and what it actually is checking for. Updated my question as well to better reflect that

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood your question haha. I'm not sure if you can tell beforehand how many packages it will return, but as fas as I know there is not.

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834090/azure-pipeline-custom-task-string-input-to-match-regex